# Do "rain and elder bloom" signify anything in Hazel's last dream?

Tags: symbolism, watership-down, richard-adams

At the end of *Watership Down*, in the Epilogue covering

> Hazel's peaceful death,

just before this happens, he has a final dream which is something about "rain and elder bloom":

> One chilly, blustery morning in March, I cannot tell exactly how many springs
> later, Hazel was dozing and waking in his burrow. He had spent a good deal of
> time there lately, for he felt the cold and could not seem to smell or run so well as
> in days gone by. He had been dreaming in a confused way -- something about rain
> and elder bloom -- when he woke to realize that there was a rabbit lying quietly
> beside him -- no doubt some young buck who had come to ask his advice.

**What, if anything, does this signify?** Is there some symbolism in elder bloom or in rain, something to make either of them a particularly apt thing to appear in the last dream of Hazel's life?

Comment: This may well be a reference back to Holly's account of the destruction of the Sandleford warren, in which he says:

> Whenever they came to a rabbit-hole, one of them would prod at it; and they kept talking all the time. I remember the smell of the elder bloom in the rain and the smell of the white sticks.